# Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/708A-1A0F/-

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file-sharing, storage-file-share

I am trying to send a list of files using tcp socket but i get this file provider error.
please help if anyone can. Thanks

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains >/storage/708A-1A0F/- CHAIN YE DILLAN DA - MUHAMMAD UMAIR ZUBAIR QADRI - OFFICIAL HD VIDEO.mp4
> at >androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:800)
> at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:442)

File Path

```
   Set<String> keys = BaseApplication.sendFileStates.keySet();
            if (keys.size() > 0) {
                for (String s : keys) {

                    File newFile = new File(s);
                    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,  "com.Jubilant.wifiproject", newFile);

                    uris.add(contentUri);


                }
                Log.d("contentUri", "onCreate: " + uris);
            }
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="."/>
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache_path"
        path="."/>
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files_path"
        path="."/>
    <external-media-path
        name="external_media_path"
        path="."/>
    <files-path
        name="files_path"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

manifest.xml:

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.Jubilant.wifiproject"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
        </provider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileProvider standard can not serve files from a removable micro sd card.

Sometimes it can when you add

```
<root name="root" path="." />
```

to your file_paths.xml file.

In other cases write your own file provider extending ContentProvider.