# Unable to share files with File Provider in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am saving .txt files in a subdirectory named "SaveFiles" under files in my applications folder. At runtime I would like to share certain files to through WhatsApp/discord/email as attachments.

When I try to share the file the chooser opens and if I select WhatsApp I'm able to see the contact and when I click on the contact I wish to share with I get a Toast message saying "Sharing Failed, please try again".

This is my provider

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.MyCompany.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

This is my res/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="all" path="." />
    <files-path name="SaveFiles" path="SaveFiles/" />
    <files-path name="Images" path="Images/" />
</paths>
```

And this is the code I'm using to share the file

```
    public  void  ShareFile(String fileName){
        try {
            File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "SaveFiles");
            File file = new File(imagePath,fileName);

            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.MyCompany.fileprovider", file);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share File"));
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "ShareFile: " + e.getMessage());
            ShowMessage(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `<files-path` I think you should have only one of such

Comment: Try file exists() and fike.canRead() before calling FileProvider.

Comment: And if you share with other apps?

Comment: @blackapps thanks for the response.
Initially there was only 1 `<files-path` but I added another to check if I could share an image instead of the text file

So the issue was that my file didn't exist. I assumed it did because it returned the correct path to me. I got another error which was root couldn't be found but I fixed that following your answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70609343/8159970). 
Thanks so much for the help!